# Could MySQL replicate external DB to cloud

Tags: mysql, google-app-engine, ubuntu, google-cloud-sql

I want to set up a master slave type situation with MySQL where the master would be on a external ubuntu server and it would replicate it to the cloudsql mysql db.

I can't find if this is possible. I found this link: https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/replication But it looks like that is for going the other direction. Just want to see if it's possible and if there are any tutorials.

Comment: I don't know anything about the Ubuntu servers but if they have an API that lets you remotely read their data you can setup a cron job on the GAE side and periodical read the changes and update the app-engine SQL instance.

Answer (score 2):

Non-Cloud -> Cloud SQL replication is not currently possible.

Answer (score 0):

You can now set up external master replication on Cloud SQL 1st gen instances, and maybe soon on 2nd gen.
Your master should be running Mysql 5.5 or 5.6 and the replica will be a Cloud SQL instance.

Here is the documentation:  https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/mysql/replication/configure-external-master